# Script to process CSS and move classes to new file?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Is there a script, or tool to remove certain classes and add them to a separate file.

I am working with SASS and would like to move the touch stuff, as well as certain other classes to a separate css file, without having to manually write them in a separate file.

Is there a tool already for this.  Or is this possible even on the SASS/Compass end before the CSS gets rendered.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks

Comment: Or is there a way to run a script after sass watch has run, and updated the css file?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's [discussion](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/241) in the Sass/Compass community to make this a native feature.

While we're waiting to see if that will be implemented, there is at least one [approach](http://jakearchibald.github.com/sass-ie/) you could try which would allow you to write all of a selector's styles in one file, while outputting certain styles to separate stylesheets. That approach takes advantage of `@content`, which you can read a short explanation of and see another example of [here](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/408#issuecomment-6086901).

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit uncertain what you mean by "is there a script or tool" to move things? I doubt there would be an automated way. But by hand just create a partial file (e.g. _touch.scss). If it is in the same directory like your main scss file add @import 'touch'; to your main file or if it is in a subdirectory @import 'example/touch.scss'; . Then move the classes and touch related stuff to the partial file. Hope that helps.